# How to assign values to an empty numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I want to know know if there is a way to assign value to a 2D numpy array

```
nbpas = 88
nbtraj = 10000
tst = np.empty((nbtraj, nbpas))
print(tst)
```

Then I would like to assign a value of 50 on the axis 0 of this array so that each row would start by 50

Can somebody help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already created the empty 2D array. I hope you are aware of the basics of the 2D numpy array. i.e it is an array of arrays.
So, you loop through the size of dimension 0 and fill all the 0th index of each array by 50.

```
nbpas = 88
nbtraj = 10000
tst = np.empty((nbtraj, nbpas))

for i in range(len(tst)):
   tst[i][0] = 50

print(tst)


[[50.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
[50.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
[50.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
...
[50.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
[50.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
[50.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]]
```

What it does is tst[i] selects all individual arrays and tst[i][0] selects the 0th index of each individual arrays in the 2D array. I just replace all 0th index with value 50.
If you print tst now, it will give output something like this

Please try this solution and if this not what you want, please share with some more information in comments.

Comment: That was actualy my question and I learned something haha  Thanks for the answer!